# Problema com select utilizando ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estou montando um select com os dados vindo da minha base.

O que acontece:  A depender do < option > que seleciono, o campo remove todos os outros.

Select populado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após selecionar alguma opção:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<select ng-model="usuarios" class="form-control">
                 <option disabled ng-selected="true">Todos</option>
                 <option ng-repeat="user in usuarios" value="{{user.id}}">{{user.nomeCompleto}}</option>
             </select>
```

Comment: Só um relato: aqui na comunidade passaram a negativar quaisquer pergunta, sem ao menos checarem o conteúdo da questão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu código está errando no `ng-model` do `<select>`, você está dando como modelo a variável `usuarios` que é a mesma variável que contém array de usuários utilizadas em `<option ng-repeat="user in usuarios">`.

Defina um novo nome para a variável usuários no seu ng-model que vai tá tudo certo. Ex: `<select ng-model="usuarioSelecionado">`.